# Discord.js Sorting Array Of Objects glitching text

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I have this code where I shuffle an array, and display the first 16 values in a discord.js embed:

```js
const items = require('../schemas/gameSchema');
const items0 = await items.find();
var shuffle = require('shuffle-array');

const items1 = shuffle(items0);

const lb = items1
  .slice(0)
  .map(
    ({ DepositAmount, BetAmount, GameName, TotalPlays }, pos) =>
      `**${GameName}** \n Initial Deposit Amount: **${commaNumber(
        DepositAmount,
      )}** <:bob:809551218217058354> \n Bet Amount:  **${commaNumber(
        BetAmount,
      )}** <:bob:809551218217058354> \n Total Game Plays : ${commaNumber(
        TotalPlays,
      )}  \n `,
  )
  .join('\n');
const lbnewnew = lb.slice(15);
const newlb = lbnewnew.toString();
let exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setTitle('Discover Games')
  .setDescription(`${newlb}`)

  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(`You can play games with /game play <game name>`);

await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

Here is the gameSchema (defined in items constant)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const adSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    User:String,
    Funds:Number,
    ProfitToClaim:Number,
    TotalProfit:Number,
    TotalLoss:Number,
    DepositAmount:Number,
    BetAmount:Number,
    TotalPlays:Number,
    TotalWins:Number,
    TotalLosses:Number,
    GameName:String,
    GameDescription:String,

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('NewGames', adSchema, 'NewGames')
```

Everything that I am taking from the schema is defined, but when I run this command, the **first** element displayed has a broken name with some random letters

[image]

or like this
[image]

There is no game called *em* or *ial* in the database, so I am not sure why this is happening

[image]

How do I stop it from saying random characters and not displaying the first element's game name? And why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're slicing off the first 15 characters (i.e. `lb.slice(15)`). Instead, you should keep the first 15 results of `items1`. You also don't need all those `toString`s and template literals.

```js
const description = items1
  .slice(0, 15)
  .map(
    ({ DepositAmount, BetAmount, GameName, TotalPlays }, pos) =>
      `**${GameName}** \n Initial Deposit Amount: **${commaNumber(
        DepositAmount,
      )}** <:bob:809551218217058354> \n Bet Amount:  **${commaNumber(
        BetAmount,
      )}** <:bob:809551218217058354> \n Total Game Plays : ${commaNumber(
        TotalPlays,
      )}  \n `,
  )
  .join('\n');

let exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setTitle('Discover Games')
  .setDescription(description)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(`You can play games with /game play <game name>`);

await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```